# Amazon MWS - Test developer scripts without having active merchant account with orders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

We have an Amazon Merchant account that's set up to be a developer. We want to test our scripts which download orders and things like that, but we have no sales/orders since we're only acting as a developer.

Is there any sort of test environment Amazon has that lets you download orders from a "fake" account? We don't know any Amazon merchants that would just let us use their access keys to test our scripts.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Amazon doesn't have sandbox or staging accounts anymore: see [Amazon MWS sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894782/amazon-mws-sandbox)
but if you download one of the client libraries, there should be a mock folder which contains mock xml requests and responses that you should be able to use to test your scripts.  Access those [here](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/182-4115030-0592649?ie=UTF8&group=orders&section=orders&version=latest).  That's probably what I'd do if I didn't have any orders to pull back.  But maybe you could list a product or two on that merchant account and place an order to get "real" data.