# Programmatic Checkout from Amazon.com ( & Amazon.in )

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-product-api

I am trying to automate the purchase of products listed on Amazon.com in Python. We would like to make 1-click purchase with the saved payment details.

I understand [Zinc](https://zincapi.com) enables the automated product purchase through their API. Does Amazon have a Sandbox account to test this ? Any idea how this can be done

Any suggestion, pointers in this regard will be really helpful.

Comment: Would [Amazon MWS sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9339579) be of any help, maybe?

Comment: Don't know if this is what you are looking for, but it might be [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-hosted/set-up-test-account.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found many sources online that stated much the same thing; that as a buyer you can not make an Amazon sandbox, but as a seller, you can (Amazon Pay)

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-a-Sandbox-account-in-Amazon

The instructions for how to make a seller virtual account can be found [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-hosted/set-up-test-account.html).

From your question, it seems like you know how to do the 1-click order thing, but [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mouse-keyboard-automation-using-python/) it is, just in case. (Basically you just use the `pyautogui` module.